# Where is c-icap's ci_thread_mutex_init() function defined?

Tags: c, squid

I am reading through Squid's c-icap source code and am unsure about a particular function definition.

The header file `ci_threads.h` includes the `<pthread.h>` header file and contains the following function declaration:

```
CI_DECLARE_FUNC(int) ci_thread_mutex_init(ci_thread_mutex_t *pmutex);
```

However, there is no accompanying `ci_threads.c` file and I do not understand where this function's body resides and how it is used. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior of this has changed over the life of c-icap.

In the [current version 0.3.5](http://sourceforge.net/projects/c-icap/), `ci_thread_mutex_init()` is defined in:

- http://sourceforge.net/p/c-icap/code/HEAD/tree/c-icap-server/trunk/c-icap/os/unix/threads.c for UNIX; and in
- http://sourceforge.net/p/c-icap/code/HEAD/tree/c-icap-server/trunk/c-icap/os/win32/threads.c for Windows.

Comment: Ok that makes sense, however, my ci_threads.h file does not contain that macro (c_icap-0.3.4)?

Comment: @geofreyrainey: I updated my answer, the most recent version of the library implements these functions differently from the older one to which my original answer referred.